# How to prevent browser from retrying GET request when hanging for response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, http-headers

I have a RoR API doing Analysis operation which can take a while (2~5mins).

Everything works fine when responses come before 2 mins. The browser just hang for 2 mins and display the result once it gets it.

Now according to HTTP 1.1 specification, modern browsers will automatically retry after waiting for a certain amount of time. So the API will get a new requests from the same client and restart everything over if the calculation is too long (like 3 or 4 mins).

How can I prevent browser from retrying ? I just want my browser to wait for the response no matter what and never retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various browser timeouts (TCP TTL, request timeout, connection timeout) are settings in the browser installation that are not configurable via a standard way like javascript.

If you really must find a way to keep the connection to the server alive for a lot longer you could try implementing [WebSockets](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails), but even this could be limited by the browser, operating system, or even network equipment (routers).

Thus it is not recommended to have your application be dependent on specific browser behavior for proper operation. It is also not recommended to have long-running processes happening in the same thread/process as the server's HTTP request handling as someone losing connection could cause the job to terminate prematurely. You might want to investigate a gem like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for moving long-running jobs to background processes.

Then you could have your webapp respond instantly to job requests with information on the status of the background job and you won't have to worry about browser request resends or losing connection, etc.